# How do I retrieve/copy lots of AWS S3 files without getting sporadic "Server failed to send complete response" exceptions?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am copying millions of S3 files during a data migration and want to perform a lot of parallel copying. I am using the Java SDK v2 API. I keep getting rare, sporadic exceptions when I try to copy a lot of S3 files at once.

I most commonly get the following exception:

```
Unable to execute HTTP request: Server failed to send complete response. The channel was closed. This may have been done by the client (e.g. because the request was aborted), by the service (e.g. because there was a handshake error, the request took too long, or the client tried to write on a read-only socket), or by an intermediary party (e.g. because the channel was idle for too long).
```

I also get:

```
Unable to execute HTTP request: The channel was closed. This may have been done by the client (e.g. because the request was aborted), by the service (e.g. because there was a handshake error, the request took too long, or the client tried to write on a read-only socket), or by an intermediary party (e.g. because the channel was idle for too long).
```

```
We encountered an internal error. Please try again. (Service: S3, Status Code: 500 ...
```

```
Unable to execute HTTP request: Channel was closed before it could be written to.
```

Here is sample code which mostly reliably seems to reliably trigger the problem for me. (the problem may depend on things like bad/busy S3 server nodes, network traffic, throttling or race conditions so it is not easy to 100% reliably reproduce the problem)

```
NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.Builder asyncHttpClientBuilder = NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder()
    .maxConcurrency(300)
    .maxPendingConnectionAcquires(500)
    .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))
    .connectionAcquisitionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
    .readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60));

S3AsyncClient s3Client = S3AsyncClient.builder()
    .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
    .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
    // You get the same failures even with retries -- it just takes longer
    .overrideConfiguration(config -> config.retryPolicy(RetryPolicy.none()).build())
    .httpClientBuilder(asyncHttpClientBuilder)
    .build();

List<CompletableFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
    String key = "zerotestfile";
    Path outFile = Paths.get("/tmp/experiment/").resolve(key + "-" + i);
    outFile.getParent().toFile().mkdirs();
    if (outFile.toFile().exists()) {
        outFile.toFile().delete();
    }
    log.info("Downloading: {} ({})", key, i);

    GetObjectRequest request = GetObjectRequest.builder()
        .bucket("my-test-bucket")
        .key(key)
        .build();

    CompletableFuture<GetObjectResponse> future = s3Client.getObject(request, AsyncResponseTransformer.toFile(outFile))
        .exceptionally(exception -> {
            log.error("Error", exception);
            return null;
        });

    futures.add(future);
}
CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0])).join();
```

500k file produced via: `dd if=/dev/zero of=zerotestfile bs=1024 count=500`

Using a retry-condition (the default) actually appears to fix the example above. But in my actual migration copying millions of files, I use a retry-condition, which helps, but I still encounter these exact exceptions produced by the example.

Additional details: My actual migration logic uses cross-region CopyObject calls. In order to make the problem simpler, I switched the example to single-region GetObject requests. I can get it to produce similar errors to the above code but I have to perform 2500 copies with maxConcurrency 2000.

I simplified my S3 config and kept only what prevented the above example from dying. I fixed the following errors by making appropriate the config changes:

Error: `Unable to execute HTTP request: Acquire operation took longer than the configured maximum time.`

Add: `.connectionAcquisitionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))`

Error: `Unable to execute HTTP request: connection timed out`

Add: `.connectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(10))`

Error: `ReadTimeoutException: null`

Add: `.readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))`

Error: `Acquire operation took longer than the configured maximum time. This indicates that a request cannot get a connection from the pool within the specified maximum time. This can be due to high request rate. Consider taking any of the following actions to mitigate the issue: increase max connections, increase acquire timeout, or slowing the request rate.`

Add: `.maxPendingConnectionAcquires(500)`

Sources: My example is originally based (but heavily modified) on a code-snippet from a bug-report in the aws java SDK which is apparently fixed: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1122

Note that various other related problems (normally also AWS Java SDK v2) get similar exceptions. I welcome any answers/comments to related problems here. If they are due to AWS SDK bugs, people open up github bug reports. See https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues

Answer (score 2):

To make the retry-logic work properly, I had to add:

`.retryCapacityCondition(null)`

(see the method documentation which specifies that you should pass in "null" to disable it)

The default behaviour is to disable retries if too many errors are hit globally by the s3 client. The problem is that I am performing massive copying and regularly hit errors and I still want to retry.

This solution seems almost obvious now but it took me over 2 days to figure this out particularly due to how hard the errors are to reproduce reliably. 99.99% of the time, it works. But my migration always failed on and skipped about a hundred files in a million. I made my own manual retry logic (because the s3-retry wasn't fixing the problem) which worked but I searched a bit harder and found this better solution.

I found it helpful to use a custom retry-policy class which logs what it is doing so I could see clearly that it was not working as I thought it should. Once I added this, I could see that in the problem cases, it was not doing my 120 retries (once every 30 seconds) at all. That's when I found retryCapacityCondition. The custom logging retry-policy:

```
            .overrideConfiguration(config ->
                config.retryPolicy(
                    RetryPolicy.builder()
                        .retryCondition(new AlwaysRetryCondition())
                        .retryCapacityCondition(null)
                        .build()
                ).build()
            )

    private static class AlwaysRetryCondition implements RetryCondition {

        private final RetryCondition defaultRetryCondition;

        public AlwaysRetryCondition() {
            defaultRetryCondition = RetryCondition.defaultRetryCondition();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldRetry(RetryPolicyContext context) {
            String exceptionMessage = context.exception().getMessage();
            Throwable cause = context.exception().getCause();
            log.debug(
                "S3 retry: shouldRetry retryCount=" + context.retriesAttempted()
                + " defaultRetryCondition=" + defaultRetryCondition.shouldRetry(context)
                + " httpstatus=" + context.httpStatusCode()
                + " " + context.exception().getClass().getSimpleName()
                + (cause != null ? " cause=" + cause.getClass().getSimpleName() : "")
                + " message=" + exceptionMessage
            );

            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void requestWillNotBeRetried(RetryPolicyContext context) {
            log.debug("S3 retry: requestWillNotBeRetried retryCount=" + context.retriesAttempted());
        }

        @Override
        public void requestSucceeded(RetryPolicyContext context) {
            if (context.retriesAttempted() > 0) {
                log.debug("S3 retry: requestSucceeded retryCount=" + context.retriesAttempted());
            }
        }

    }
```

For reference, this is the config I use:

```
        NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.Builder asyncHttpClientBuilder = NettyNioAsyncHttpClient.builder()
            .maxConcurrency(500)
            .maxPendingConnectionAcquires(10000)
            .connectionMaxIdleTime(Duration.ofSeconds(600))
            .connectionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(20))
            .connectionAcquisitionTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(60))
            .readTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(120));

        // Add retry behaviour
        final long CLIENT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 600000;
        final int NUMBER_RETRIES = 60;
        final long RETRY_BACKOFF_MILLIS = 30000;
        ClientOverrideConfiguration overrideConfiguration = ClientOverrideConfiguration.builder()
            .apiCallTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(CLIENT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS))
            .apiCallAttemptTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(CLIENT_TIMEOUT_MILLIS))
            .retryPolicy(RetryPolicy.builder()
                .numRetries(NUMBER_RETRIES)
                .backoffStrategy(
                    FixedDelayBackoffStrategy.create(Duration.of(RETRY_BACKOFF_MILLIS, ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
                )
                .throttlingBackoffStrategy(BackoffStrategy.none())
                .retryCondition(new AlwaysRetryCondition())
                // retryCapacityCondition(null) fixes the rare s3-copy-errors
                //  this global max-retries was kicking in and preventing individual copy-requests from retrying
                .retryCapacityCondition(null)
                .build()
            ).build();

        S3AsyncClient s3Client = S3AsyncClient.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(awsCredentialsProvider)
            .region(Region.US_EAST_1)
            .httpClientBuilder(asyncHttpClientBuilder)
            .overrideConfiguration(overrideConfiguration)
            .build();
```